# hide keyboard on done button press while using multiautocompletetextview

Tags: android

I have a multiautocompletetextview

```
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView 
            android:id="@+id/email_editText_auto"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/enter_email_address_hint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" 
           />
```

When I press the done button nothing seems to happen .How can I hide the keyboard when I press the done button? or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a silly mistake just had to use  `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = 
        (InputMethodManager) context.
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
        this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```